# Unnesting a dataframe within a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, confidence-interval, hmisc

I have been trying to calculate confidence intervals for binomial distributions through the Hmisc R package. Specifically, I used the binconf function which does its job perfectly.

```
library(plyr)
library(Hmisc)

Student <- c("A", "B", "C")
TP <- c(13, 36, 43)
obs.pos <- c(16, 37, 48)

df <- data.frame(Student, TP, obs.pos)

df1 <- df %>% 
  plyr::mutate(Sen = binconf(TP, obs.pos, alpha = 0.05, method = "wilson", return.df = TRUE))

df1 %>% View()

#  Student TP obs.pos Sen.PointEst Sen.Lower Sen.Upper
#1       A 13      16    0.8125000 0.5699112 0.9340840
#2       B 36      37    0.9729730 0.8617593 0.9986137
#3       C 43      48    0.8958333 0.7783258 0.9546783
```

Unfortunately, I feel that the function creates a data frame within my original data frame and that does not allow me to apply basic functions on my output anymore. For instance, I cannot select columns (by using dplyr) or round digits because R is not able to find the created columns (such as Sen.PointEst, Sen.Lower, Sen.Upper). Below, the structure of my output.

```
df1 %>% str()

#'data.frame':  3 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ Student: Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 2 3
# $ TP     : num  13 36 43
# $ obs.pos: num  16 37 48
# $ Sen    :'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
#  ..$ PointEst: num  0.812 0.973 0.896
#  ..$ Lower   : num  0.57 0.862 0.778
#  ..$ Upper   : num  0.934 0.999 0.955
```

I would like to have all the columns at the first level of my output so that I can easily apply all the normal functions to my output.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a column that is `data.frame` inside a `data.frame`.  One option to flatten out the `data.frame` will be to call `data.frame` within `do.call`

```
dfN <- do.call(data.frame, df1)
```

---

Or another option is to call the `binconf` within `do`

```
df %>% 
  do(data.frame(., Sen = binconf(.$TP, .$obs.pos, alpha = 0.05, method = "wilson")))
```

Comment: I like the second option but it returns an error if one cell in the output has NA value. This is the message that I got. `Error in if (x > 0) x/(x + qf(1 - alpha/2, nu1, nu2) * (n - x + 1)) else 0 : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

Comment: @MichaelMatta  If you do `binconf(df$TP, obs.pos, alpha = 0.05, method = "wilson")` it returns a `matrix`, with `return.df = TRUE`.  I guess it won't work with `NA` values.  Create an index and then update it. i.e. `i1 <- !is.na(df$TP); binconf(df$TP[i1], obs.pos, alpha = 0.05, method = "wilson")`

Comment: I realized I didn't have missing value but real zeros. The issue was solved by replacing `.$obs.pos` to `obs.pos` within your code. Do you agree?

Comment: @MichaelMatta  Yes, I completely forgot about that variable.  you are right

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on JWilliman's good answer, consider using map() with possibly() to handle NAs

```
Student <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
TP <- c(13, 36, 43, NA, 0)
obs.pos <- c(16, 37, 48, NA, 0)
df <- data.frame(Student, TP, obs.pos)

df %>%
  group_by(Student) %>%
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(aa = map(data, possibly(
    ~binconf(.$TP, .$obs.pos, return.df = TRUE), NULL))) %>% 
  unnest_wider(aa) %>% 
  unnest_wider(data)
  

# A tibble: 5 × 6
# Groups:   Student [5]
  Student    TP obs.pos PointEst   Lower   Upper
  <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 A          13      16    0.812   0.570   0.934
2 B          36      37    0.973   0.862   0.999
3 C          43      48    0.896   0.778   0.955
4 D          NA      NA   NA      NA      NA    
5 E           0       0  NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option using the `tidyverse` package, that will cope with missing values. This currently adds a couple of extra columns, which may be a bug??

```
library(tidyverse)

Student <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
TP <- c(13, 36, 43, NA, 0)
obs.pos <- c(16, 37, 48, NA, 0)



df <- data.frame(Student, TP, obs.pos)


df %>% 
  nest(TP, obs.pos) %>% 
  mutate(out = map_if(
    data, .p = ~ !is.na(.$TP) & !is.na(.$obs.pos),
    .f = ~ Hmisc::binconf(.$TP, .$obs.pos, return.df = TRUE))) %>% 
  unnest(data, out) 


 Student TP obs.pos  PointEst     Lower     Upper TP1 obs.pos1
1       A 13      16 0.8125000 0.5699112 0.9340840  NA       NA
2       B 36      37 0.9729730 0.8617593 0.9986137  NA       NA
3       C 43      48 0.8958333 0.7783258 0.9546783  NA       NA
4       D NA      NA        NA        NA        NA  NA       NA
5       E  0       0       NaN       NaN       NaN  NA       NA
```